# Invisible character leads to Unexpected EOF error

Tags: javascript, character, eof, invisible

While trying to handle a string I am facing

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

I have no control on how the string is generated.  I managed to isolate the problematic character(s) by dichotomy with `substring()`, however it doesn't get printed either by `console.log()` or by `JSON.parse()` : I get

```
> console.log(c);
""
> JSON.parse(c);
""
```

yet

```
> c.length;
1
```

All I know is that it is followed by a `\n`.

How can I identify it and get rid of it ?

### Update

```
> console.log(encodeURIComponent(c));
%E2%80%A8
```

[Is this even a character ??](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: What code gives you that error?

Comment: @p.s.w.g The error is thrown by PhantomJS code on the Apify platform.

Comment: Try trimming the input: `JSON.parse(c.trim())`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `trim()` indeed removes the character, but since it's in the middle of the string I cannot really use it.

Comment: BTW that's a `LINE SEPARATOR` character (U+2028), UTF-8 encoded, then URI encoded. This *is* considered to be [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) by Unicode, so it *should* be fine, but perhaps PhantomJS is using a different definition of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the only problematic character, and since its percent-encoding has been identified, a solution is to replace the decoded percent-encoding string :

```
> c.length;
1
> let badchar = decodeURI("%E2%80%A8");
> let regex = new RegExp(badchar, "g");
> newc = c.replace(regex, "");
> newc.length;
0
```

Or if for some reason `RegExp` is not available :

```
> newc = c.split(badchar).join("")
```